# What is the $user array consists of for Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, users

I couldn't find a good reference to what the $user object consists of. I know $user->uid provides to uid. What else?

Answer (score 0):

The Drupal 7 $user object consists of the following when doing an output of dsm($user):

If your wanted the name, you would do: $user->name or roles would be: $user->roles[2]

[image]